# Effect of pathloss on signal power

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, multipath

Consider I have two transmitters $tx_1$ and $tx_2$ at say a distance of $d_1=5\text{ m}$ and $d_2 = 15\text{ m}$ respectively from a receiver. Now, if I consider the effect of path loss in such a system and plot the power spectral density for both the transmitters, the PSD of $tx_1$ should be higher than the PSD of $tx_2$. In my simulation, I notice that the PSD of $tx_1$ has its peak at $130\text{ dB}_m$ whereas PSD of $tx_2$ has its peak at $160\text{ dB}_m$.

I am not sure if I am missing something or I have understood this wrong. I think the peak should be vice versa, i.e., $130\text{ dB}_m$ for $tx_2$ and $160\text{ dB}_m$ for $tx_1$. I have used a reference distance $d_0=1\text{ m}$, pathloss exponent $n=3$ and $\lambda=3e8/2.4e9$.

This is the formula I have been using for calculating the pathloss:
$PL(dB)= -20\log_{10}(\lambda/(4\pi d_0))+10 n \log_{10}(d/d0)$

$PL(linear) = 10^{PL(dB))/10}$

Once , I have the PL, I am multiplying this PL with the signal to be transmitted. Could someone advise where I might be going wrong.

Comment: I think you have some typos. Based on your second paragraph, I assume you mean that you're observing a higher received power from the transmitter that is farther away. That doesn't square with what you said in the first paragraph. Where are you doing this simulation? It sounds as if you have a miscalculation somewhere.

Comment: I have edited my question @JasonR. I am simulating this using Matlab

Comment: I have realized that I have been considering a positive value of $PL(dB)$  which would act like a gain rather than as loss. When I consider the negative value of $PL(dB)$, I am able to get a lower received power for the transmitter that is farther away. I would however like to know if the above formula and parameters that I have been using are the right ones? I am asking this because, the transmitted power is $10dbM$ whereas the power at the receiver at a distance of $5m$  is $-120dbM$. Could there be so much impact on the signal power due to the path loss?

Comment: The rule of thumb for path loss in free space for stationary channel is about $10log10(r^2)$, in the case of fading channel it further decreases, but this degradation is about few dB usually

Comment: That means that the formula that I have been using to compute the pathloss is probably an incorrect one since the signal attenuation is too high @Serj